# Productivity tool to generate fluent equivalent of non-fluent class?

Tags: c#, fluent

One of the basic features of fluent interfaces is that methods that would conventionally be declared as `void` will instead return something usable, most often the instance of the class they belong to (i.e., `this`). StringBuilder exemplifies this convention, and while it's not *fully* fluent per-se, it does give you the convenience of chained method calls:

```
sb.Append("Foo")
  .Append("Bar")
  .AppendLine();
```

`System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder`, however, doesn't follow this convention; the methods are all `void`.

A quick and dirty way to tidy this up could be to encapsulate a private TagBuilder (`_instance`) in a `FluentTagBuilder` class, then implement all the same methods, but delegate the work to the instance and return `this` instead of `void`.

What is the best not-so-quick-and-dirty way to achieve this? Inheritance obviously won't do, since the methods would vary only by return type. I'd rather keep it simple and not involve mock/substitution frameworks if possible. Thanks for any wisdom you can share!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks. I disagree with the consensus (leading keywords in tags make it easier to tell which browser tab is which, or which search result is most likely to have what I want, etc.); that said, since there *is* already a consensus, I'll try to conform to it from now on. :)

Comment: The most popular tag gets added to the title. They already thought of that.

Comment: Once again, I should have just let go & trusted SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a small Git repository, and started a tool for doing this.

It is very amateur, is badly coded, and has a lot of issues yes, but you it is very simple and you can adapt it.

Fluentizer grabs a class, and through reflection generates a new class, encapsulating the original methods.

Check the [Fluentizer](https://github.com/eklam/Fluentizer) here.

Comment: I like it; it gets the job done. I see only two easily-corrected issues:

*A)* `static` methods on the original should be declared as `static`
*B)* `return _this;` returns the encapsulated (non-fluent) instance. You actually want to `return this;` to maintain fluency. 

Other than that, well done... it's totally usable. If I were going to enhance it, I would just use an argument for the name of the class to be fluentized, and the rest of the args for namespaces in the `using` block -- maybe even give it an interactive mode with prompts where you can set these.

Comment: Yes.. I was making it generate as Extension method, and then I changed it in a hurry, it is corrected now. It'd be nice if it were some plugin, I'll look into it when I get more time

Comment: FYI I'm making some changes as I go along, and I'm happy to share them. This patch just substitutes tabs for spaces (stops Visual Studio from complaining), and skips members inherited from System.Object: https://www.dropbox.com/s/leggd2sm57thptw/fluentizer1.diff; I'm also considering adding an enclosing namespace "Fluency", plus a static partial class "FluentExtensions" which adds an `.AsFluent()` extension method to the target class. Ping me with some sort of contact info if you're interested in any of that.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extension method to propagate the builder object:

```
public static T Do<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
{
    action(obj);
    return obj;
}

TagBuilder builder;
builder.Do(b => b.SetInnerText("text"))
       .Do(b => b.AddCssClass("class"))
       .Do(b => b.GenerateId("id"));
```

Comment: I started off in that direction myself, but I wound up with something requiring more syntax than the raw method calls I was trying to replace. :) I didn't find a way around that without encapsulating and delegating to the utility class.